# In sklearn's classification report, is f1 the best accuracy measure?

Tags: classification, model-evaluations

In the [classification_report](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.classification_report.html) provided by `sklearn`, which score should I look at to make the best determination of the accuracy of my model?

```
             precision    recall  f1-score   support

          0       0.70      0.68      0.69      5007
          1       0.65      0.54      0.59      2270
          2       0.37      0.22      0.28       614
          3       0.74      0.30      0.42       252
          4       0.59      0.42      0.49       262
          5       0.35      0.11      0.17       455
          6       0.34      0.23      0.27       248
          7       0.09      0.05      0.06       133
          8       0.38      0.15      0.21       395
          9       0.43      0.31      0.36       182
         10       0.23      0.12      0.16       230

avg / total       0.60      0.52      0.55     10048
```

As far as I understand it:

- Precision tells us the amount of samples the classifier has *correctly*
  marked as true positive out of all positive results.
- Recall tells us about the number of samples the classifier was able
  to get correct out of *all* samples in the set.
- F1-score is the harmonic mean of precision and recall.

Maybe I'm misinterpreting the `classification_report`, but wouldn't the `f1-score` give the best view on the performance of the classifier?

Answer (score 3):

You got `recall` incorrectly. It does not mean "correct out of all the samples".
$\hspace{50mm}$[image]

Looking at the image,

$\hspace{50mm}$ `Recall` = $\frac{TP}{TP+FN}$

It is explained [here](http://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support.html#sklearn.metrics.precision_recall_fscore_support).

From the above documentation, you can also see that you can modify your `F-beta score` to suite which to weigh more, precision or recall. Therefore, `f-score` would give you an overall of how good your classifier is, but if you need to know at which samples your classifier fails, you need `precision` and `recall`.

Comment: Answer might be improved, if it helped correct OP's misunderstanding regarding "best" metric. The metric to select a model on is the one that most closely matches the goal and intended use for a model. As you suggest, you can also look at multiple metrics if you are interested in error analysis.

Answer (score 0):

F1 is only useful if Precision and Recall are similar.

That's why SKLearn has micro and macro (weighted) F1.

In Data Science interviews, answering F1 is the most important measure is a sign of a beginner. I tend to agree ... there are so many things to watch out. E.g.

- Accuracy kFold cross-validation
- Standard Deviation high or low? A high level is a sign of a problem (e.g. >5%)
- What does the Learning Curve tell you? Do you have enough data?
- A Recall of 0.70 might be great if you have 0.01% label 1
- With a highly unbalanced dataset, AUROC is important.
- I prefer a slightly lower F1 with a low variance algorithm (e.g. Logistic Regression)
- A high F1 score might not be that great if you overfit a Decision Tree
- ....

good luck!